# What is wrong with [boost.di] unique scope

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

I begin to use boost.di and I don't get about unique scope. Documentation says:

> Scope representing unique/per request value. A new instance will be
>   provided each time type will be requested.

```
#include <boost/di.hpp>
#include <assert.h>
namespace di = boost::di;

class server {
public:
};
int main()
{
    di::policies::constructible();
    di::injector<client> injector = di::make_injector(//<my_conf>
        di::bind<server>().in(di::unique)
    );
    std::shared_ptr<server> server1 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<server>>();
    std::shared_ptr<server> server2 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<server>>();
    assert(server1 != server2);
}
```

My assert failed! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trully believe you already found your answer for this, but I was studying this library and stumbled upon your question without answer here and thought it might be useful for others to find a written answer.

So, the key poiny is the **return type** of di::make_injector.

If you write like this snippet below you'll see the difference between asking for auto vs restricting it to injector.

```cpp
  auto injector = di::make_injector(//<my_conf>
          di::bind<server>().in(di::unique)
      );
  std::cout << typeid(injector).name() << '\n';

  di::injector<client> injector2 = di::make_injector(//<my_conf>
          di::bind<server>().in(di::unique)
    );
  std::cout << typeid(injector2).name() << '\n';
```

For reference, I put together a test code (written for testing with Catch2) which one can further explore the idea.

```cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>

#include <boost/di.hpp>

namespace di = boost::di;


struct server {
  virtual ~server() noexcept = default;
  // cannot be pure virtual because server has to be creatable to be called explicitly in
  // the injector call.
  virtual void dummy(){}; 
};

struct client : server {
  void dummy() override {}
};


TEST_CASE("injector","[Unique scope should return new objects at the same type creation call]")
{
  di::policies::constructible();
  
  auto injector = di::make_injector(//<my_conf>
          di::bind<server>().to<client>().in(di::unique)
      );

  SECTION("new_objects"){
    std::shared_ptr<server> server1 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<server>>();
    std::shared_ptr<server> server2 = injector.create<std::shared_ptr<server>>();
    CHECK((server1) != (server2));

    auto [server3, server4] = injector.create<std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<server>,std::shared_ptr<server>>>();
    CHECK(server3 != server4);

  }

  SECTION("in_constructor"){
    struct example {
      example(std::shared_ptr<server> sp1 /*unique*/
          , std::shared_ptr<server> sp2 /*unique*/
          ) {
        CHECK(sp1 != sp2);
      }
    };

    auto ex = injector.create<example>();
  }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody to use this good library.

Comment: The purpose of the first snippet is not intelligible to the reader without the output for `std::cout`. Please consider adding it instead of forcing user to run it to find out.